# Rails User Membership Groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to make a application where a user belongs to multiple courses and multiple assignments belong to a course.  I'm using devise for the user model.  I want to be able to find all the courses a user belongs to and all the assignments their courses have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User model:
has_and_belongs_to_many :course
has_many :assignments, :through => :courses

Course model:
has_and_belongs_to :user
has_many :assignments

Assignment model:
belongs_to :course

this requires an intermediate table CoursesUsers with columns user_id and course_id
and column course_id in Assignment

with this give you can do things like
current_user.courses
current_user.assignments
some_course.assignments
some_course.users
(assuming there is a current_user or some_course)

Read about details here: [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org./association_basics.html) Especially how to setup the has_and_belongs_to_many association

Comment: When I try and run the server I get undefined method `has_and_belongs_to' for #<Class:0x2ba400d71728>

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Great Answer